# Cover browser with fixed aspect ratio div, cover but allow to overflow sideways without scroll, but vertically with scroll

Tags: html, css, sass

The div will contain an image and will be of fixed aspect ratio for example 1920x1080.

The div will fit the height of the browser window except when it doesn't reach the sides then it will fit the width and the bottom can be reached by scrolling.

When the browser window is tall the div will be it's height and the excess width will be allowed to expand beyond the windows width equally to the left and right.

Through all this, placing absolute positioning on the div will allow percentage positioning of elements within it wether the origin is off screen or not.

I have done this once before but can't find the code and I need to do it again.

Take it as a challenge if you like its driving me bonkers trying to do it again.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like this... Image Size at 1920x1080
Aspect Ratio at 1 : 0.5625

Image at 100vh of browser

Width at which image
does not fit browser is at
100vh / 0.5625

Code

    .div {
        height: 100vh;
        @media(max-width: calc(100vh / 0.5625)){
            height: auto;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    }